# HTML added in link function won't bind to scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need a template that changes depending on an object on the scope. Because it's an object and not a string, I can't use a template function, so I'm using the link function to add the html to the element. Of course my html needs to be explicitly $interpolated now, so here's what I end up with:

```
scope: {
    obj: "=ngModel",
    type: "<"
},
controllerAs: "display",
controller: function() {
    let display = this;
    // sets bunch of other functions, including booleanLabel and displayData
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    let display = scope;

    function template(type) {
        switch (type) {
            case ObjTypes.X:
                return `<button ng-click="display.toggleBoolean(display.obj)">
                          {{display.booleanLabel(display.obj.data)}}
                        </button>`;
            case ObjTypes.Y:
                return `<button>
                          {{display.displayData(display.obj.data)}}
                        </button>`;
            }
        }

        element.html($interpolate(template(display.type))(display));
    }
```

This doesn't work. But here's the weird thing: when I replace `display.obj` with just `obj`, the value gets through. But the functions need to be called with `display.function()`.

I suspect it has to do with the fact that obj is put on the scope from the outside, while the functions are put on the scope by the controller, but it's incredibly weird and confusing. And what's worse, the ng-click doesn't trigger. Whether I use `display.toggle()` or just `toggle()` doesn't matter. But display.booleanLabel() and display.displayData() work fine, as long as I pass the obj, rather than display.obj.

What's going on here? And how do I make this easier to understand and maintain?

I'm using Angular 1.5, and I use controllerAs: 'display' and let display = scope to make sure my scope uses the same name everywhere. The point is to keep it easier to understand, but that's clearly not working here.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use ng-if in template.

Second, template can be a function.

Third, if you add new html elements - usually you need to $compile it. Not sure what are you tying to do with interpolate...

Comment: I was under the impression $interpolate would be enough. I'm not introducing any new directives to the dom, just data bindings. I'm currently trying an alternative route with ng-if, but that also runs into surprising difficulties. Template function won't work, because it won't have access to the scope, only to attributes, which will be strings.